# Append vs extend efficiency

Tags: python, list, performance

Here is some code that I wrote using Python:

```
from math import sqrt
abundant_list = []

for i in range(12,28123+1):
    dividor_list = [1]
    for j in range(2, int(sqrt(i))+1):
        if i%j == 0:
            dividor_list.extend([i/j,j])
    if sum(dividor_list) > i:
        abundant_list.append(i)

print abundant_list
```

As you can see, the code is really trying to be efficient as much as possible.

There is any difference if I use `list.append` twice, or `list.extend` just once?
I know it can be minor differences, but I would really like to know that :)

Comment: I would be pretty surprised if `extend` wasn't faster than 2 `.appends`

Comment: If I were to optimize this, I'd use [the sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to find primes up to `sqrt(28123)`, then for each `i`, I'd factorize it and use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get all ways to combine the factors into divisors, and finally sum those.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
import timeit

def append2x(foo):
    foo.append(1)
    foo.append(1)

def extend_lst(foo):
    foo.extend([1,1])

def extend_tup(foo):
    foo.extend((1,1))


l1 = []
l2 = []
l3 = []

print timeit.timeit('append2x(l1)',setup = 'from __main__ import append2x,l1')
print timeit.timeit('extend_lst(l2)',setup = 'from __main__ import extend_lst,l2')
print timeit.timeit('extend_tup(l3)',setup = 'from __main__ import extend_tup,l3')
```

Here's a simple benchmark.  My results (os-X, 10.5.8, core2duo, FWIW):

```
0.520906925201  #append
0.602569103241  #extend-list
0.357008934021  #extend-tuple
```

And the same ordering of the results my linux box (Ubuntu, x86-64 core i7):

```
0.307395935059  #append
0.319436073303  #extend-list
0.238317012787  #extend-tuple
```

To me, this says that `extend` is quicker than `append`, but that creating a `list` is relatively expensive compared to creating a `tuple`

---

## **EDIT**

Pointed out in the comments below, because of the immutability of tuples, the interpreter can optimize the creation of the tuple out (it creates the tuple once and re-uses it over and over).  If we change the code to:

```
def extend_lst(foo):  
    v = 1
    foo.extend([v,v]) 

def extend_tup(foo):
    v = 1
    foo.extend((v,v))
```

The timings are virtually identical:

```
0.297003984451  #append
0.344678163528  #extend-list
0.292304992676  #extend-tuple
```

Although `tuple` still consistently beats the list version and barely edges out the `append` version for all of the trials I have done.

One thing that I'm taking away from this is that if you're iterating over an object that consists of all literals, choose a `tuple` over a `list`.  If it doesn't consist entirely of literals, then it really doesn't matter whether you choose `list` or `tuple`.

Comment: Well, just learned the "time.clock" function, and suprisingly, it's shows that extend is much slower... will edit my message

Comment: The tuple version is faster because the tuple you use is a literal and hence re-used (cf. the bytecode), so it doesn't have to be constructed again and again. Use variables (e.g. pass an object to append to all functions) and the difference will be reduced.

Comment: Great answers guys, thanks. Always worth opening new question, always learning new stuff :)

Comment: @delnan -- Great catch!  Although, `tuple` still edges it out after a few repeated runs.

Comment: @mgilson:  Even with passing in variables the tuple version takes 90% of the individual appends.

Comment: @delnan -- I was working on it.  I've added an edit explaining this stuff.  I don't usually leave the poor timings in the answer, but in this case, I felt it was instructive to leave both versions to show how literal tuples are much faster than literal lists, but when using variables they're relatively close.

Comment: @Infinity -- `time.clock` is not the right way to time a piece of code.  There are a lot of subtleties that you need to consider when trying to benchmark things (as you can see in the error of my original answer).  The `timeit` module keeps you from having to worry about 90% of those subtleties -- SO users usually catch the other 10% ;-)

Comment: OK, next time will know to use timeit:) Really appreciate your answers guys, learned a lot from it :)

Comment: @Infinity -- I learned something from this one too :) -- I should have looked at the bytecode before posting :-P.

Comment: A better speedup is to cache the function lookup outside the nested loops:  `dividor_list_extend = dividor_list.extend`.

Answer (score 24):

*edit: As others note in the comments, there is no tuple comprehension in Python, as that syntax is already used for generator expressions. I have clarified the description.*

It is also worth pointing out that the answer to this question hinges on the small size of the list/tuple that is added on each iteration. For larger lists, extend is clearly superior (and lists vs tuples does not make a difference). Starting with [mgilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/748858/mgilson)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14446207/5635856), I checked behaviour for collections with 600 items, rather than 2:
Calling append 600 times takes 8 times as long as using `extend()` with a manually defined list/tuple (i.e. `[v,v,v,v,v,v,v...]`):

```
42.4969689846
5.45146393776
5.38034892082
```

The bulk of these five seconds is actually the list/tuple creation. Preparing it before the `timeit` call brings times for extend down to

```
1.42491698265
0.657584905624
```

for list and tuple, respectively.

For a more realistic (and fairer) case, one can dynamically generate the data within the function call:

```
import timeit

def append_loop(foo, reps):
    for i in range(reps):
        foo.append(i)

def append_comp(foo, reps):
    [foo.append(i) for i in range(reps)]

def extend_lst(foo, reps):
    foo.extend([i for i in range(reps)])

def extend_genexp(foo, reps):
    foo.extend((i for i in range(reps)))

repetitions = 600

print timeit.timeit('append_loop([], repetitions)', setup='from __main__ import append_loop, repetitions')
print timeit.timeit('append_comp([], repetitions)', setup='from __main__ import append_comp, repetitions')
print timeit.timeit('extend_lst([], repetitions)', setup='from __main__ import extend_lst, repetitions')
print timeit.timeit('extend_genexp([], repetitions)', setup='from __main__ import extend_genexp, repetitions')
```

(Append is implemented both via for-loop and list comprehension to factor out efficiency differences between the two ways of looping.)

Timings are:

```
53.8211231232
57.1711571217
19.8829259872
28.5986201763
```

As we can see, extend with list comprehension is still over two times faster than appending. Generator expressions appear noticeably slower than list comprehension. `append_comp` only introduces unnecessary list creation overhead.

Comment: The later (`extend_tup`) is in fact a genexp and not a tuple, which explains the slowness.

Comment: You're right about the output type, my mistake. However, I just tested tuple comprehension and it provides the same speed as the genexp. List comprehension is still faster. Obviously, if the tuple was precomputed the call would be faster, but the same is true for a precomputed list.

Comment: Your benchmark is biased, because its include the time needed to built the lists and tuples. Without that, extending a list with a tuple is a bit faster (at least for me, using python 3.5).

Comment: Your test is misleading and the proper test shows that append is the fastest method. Both appends tests that you used are appending an item at a time, but the extend() are for whole list. When I changed the code of the append_comp so the append is out of the comprehension list (as in the last 2 tests) the times are (in my tests on my slow machine using Jupyter lab interpreter) for the last 3 tests: 91, 104, 148 seconds respectfully.

Comment: @Zvi, I'm not sure what you find misleading. The original question asked whether using append multiple times is faster or slower than using extend once, so that code difference is by design. Your suggested change does not provide the correct result, as it would append the entire reps list as a single item, rather than appending the individual elements, i.e. you would get [[1,2,3...]] instead of [1,2,3...].

Comment: @yoch I included the list creation as part of the call for fairness, as including the iteration can't be avoided for append. You are correct, though, that the list comprehension accounts for most of the time. On my current setup with Python 3.7, extend with precomputed lists/tuples took 0.9 seconds, vs 17 and 25 seconds for list/generator comprehension. The difference between precomputed list and tuple is less than 0.04 seconds, though, so I'm not convinced that tuples would be consistently faster.

Comment: Well explained, I would like to correct you that `(i for i in range(reps))` is a generator,  not a tuple

Answer (score 0):

They take exact same time.

Here is the time taken for your code:

With `dividor_list.extend([i/j,j])`

```
>>> 
0:00:00.410000
>>> 
0:00:00.383000
>>> 
0:00:00.389000
```

With `dividor_list.append(i/j); dividor_list.append(j)`

```
>>> 
0:00:00.400000
>>> 
0:00:00.390000
>>> 
0:00:00.381000
```

Comment: You'll have to include your timing code, as that's easy to mess up. And since you apparently didn't use `timeit`, you'll have to justify not using `timeit` ;-)

Comment: mgilson's benchmark suggests `dividor_list.extend((i/j,j))` is more efficient than both because it doesn't create an intermediate list.  Creating an intermediate tuple is cheaper.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski No, it just shows that one `LOAD_CONST` is faster than a 2 to 3 `LOAD_FAST`s, some other operations, and a `BUILD_LIST` ;-)

Comment: @delnan.  Point taken.  The tuple version still clocks a little faster on my system with your suggested modifications.  But it's too little improvement to really care which is used.

Answer (score 0):

## just another benchmark

this time in **ipython**. Maybe useful if you are too lazy to create a new python script.

```
In [12]: %%time
    ...: l = []
    ...: for ii in range(10000):
    ...:     l += [ii]
    ...: 
CPU times: user 886 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 886 µs
Wall time: 889 µs

In [13]: %%time
    ...: l = []
    ...: for ii in range(10000):
    ...:     l.append(ii)
    ...: 
CPU times: user 669 µs, sys: 92 µs, total: 761 µs
Wall time: 763 µs
```