# What is the fastest approach to combine two large dictionaries by key?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, python-2.x

I have two large dictionaries. This is an example to demonstrate but you can imagine each dictionary having close to 100k records:

```
d1 = {
    '0001': [('skiing',0.789),('snow',0.65),('winter',0.56)],
    '0002': [('drama', 0.89),('comedy', 0.678),('action',-0.42),
             ('winter',-0.12),('kids',0.12)]
}

d2 = {
    '0001': [('action', 0.89),('funny', 0.58),('sports',0.12)],
    '0002': [('dark', 0.89),('Mystery', 0.678),('crime',0.12), ('adult',-0.423)]
}
```

I want to have a dictionary that has combined values by key from each dictionary:

```
{
    '0001': [
        ('skiing', 0.789), ('snow', 0.65), ('winter', 0.56),
        [('action', 0.89), ('funny', 0.58), ('sports', 0.12)]
    ],
    '0002': [
        ('drama', 0.89), ('comedy', 0.678), ('action', -0.42),
        ('winter', -0.12), ('kids', 0.12),
        [('dark', 0.89), ('Mystery', 0.678), ('crime', 0.12), ('adult', -0.423)]
    ]
}
```

The way I would achieve this is:

```
for key, value in d1.iteritems():
    if key in d2:
        d1[key].append(d2[key])
```

But after reading in many places I found out that `iteritems()` is really slow and doesn't actually use C data structures to do it, but uses Python functions. How can I do this combine/merge process fast and efficiently?

Comment: I assume your code snippet should have some `d2` in there?

Comment: you already have `value`, why access `d1[key]` again?

Comment: @Bubai sorry there was a bug in the snippet. Updated

Comment: shouldn't you be using `extend()` instead of `append()`?

Comment: @Bubai I think performance problem is in `for key,value in d1.iteritems()` more than `extend` vs `append`. At least that what I think. not sure :(

Comment: It is also worth noting that this approach will LOSE any keys that were only in d2, but not d1. So it is only valid if the keys for d2 are either identical or a subset to d1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input has to be dicts, I don't think you will find anything faster than `iteritems`. If one dict has notably fewer keys than the other, you should iterate over the smaller one to cut down on iterations.

Any solution that involves converting your dict into a different data type will cost way more in creation time than it could ever save you through efficient loops. Instead of iterating once, you have to iterate three times (twice to create the two new collections and once to run your merge).

If you do have the option of using a different data type when initially creating your collections, iteration over lists (using indices instead of keys) will be slightly faster. Of course, this means you lose all other advantages that dicts might offer you.

`timeit` gives the following speeds for various suggested approaches, given two dicts of 200 keys (same keys for both dicts):

- iteritem (as given n question): 23.0725131035
- [iterate over set intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29127701/5635856): 31.7572350502
- [concatenating Counter objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29127420/5635856): 125.085702181
- iterate over lists: 16.3535020351

To give set intersection another chance, let only half the keys of `d2` actually match those of `d1`:

- iteritem: 15.5433290005
- set intersection: 22.1796240807

As we can see, the cost of creating two sets still outweighs any potential benefit (at least in Python 2, where `dict.keys()` gives a list, rather than a set-operation-compatible view).

### Side note: Append vs Extend

In your current code example

```
for key,value in d1.iteritems():
    if key in d2:
        d1[key].append(d2[key])
```

you are appending the entire list of `d2` as a single new item of the list in `d1`, rather than merging the lists (`[1,2].append([3,4]) == [1,2,[3,4]]`, not `[1,2,3,4]`). You could loop over the list from `d2` and call append multiple times, but `extend()` will be faster.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to merge the `dicts`

```
from collections import Counter
res = Counter(d1) + Counter(d2)
>>>res
Counter({'0001': [('skiing', 0.789), ('snow', 0.65), ('winter', 0.56 **...**
```

**For example**

```
from collections import Counter

d1 = {"a":[1,2], "b":[]}
d2 = {"a":[1,3], "b":[5,6]}

res = Counter(d1)+Counter(d2)

>>>res
Counter({'b': [5, 6], 'a': [1, 2, 1, 3]})
```

Even this approach support unequal number of keys in `dicts`, like

```
d1 = {"a":[1,2], "b":[]}
d2 = {"a":[1,3], "b":[5,6], "c":["ff"]}

>>>res
Counter({'c': ['ff'], 'b': [5, 6], 'a': [1, 2, 1, 3]})
```

Comment: `dict(res)` wouldn't this be a very expensive process.

Answer (score 2):

```
for k, v in d2.items():
    if k in d1:
        d1[k].extend(v)
    else:
        d1[k] = v
```

Comment: I think extend is slower based on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446128/python-append-vs-extend-efficiency

Answer (score 1):

```
d1 = {'0001': [('skiing',0.789),('snow',0.65),('winter',0.56)],'0002': [('drama', 0.89),('comedy', 0.678),('action',-0.42), ('winter',-0.12),('kids',0.12)]}
d2 = {'0001': [('action', 0.89),('funny', 0.58),('sports',0.12)],'0002': [('dark', 0.89),('Mystery', 0.678),('crime',0.12), ('adult',-0.423)]}

for x in set(d1).intersection(set(d2)):
    d1[x].extend(d2[x])
```

maybe you can try this program. At first I get the intersection between d1 and d2, therefor I could execute least iterate times for this task.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by -

```
>>> d1 = {'0001': [('skiing',0.789),('snow',0.65),('winter',0.56)],'0002': [('drama', 0.89),('comedy', 0.678),('action',-0.42), ('winter',-0.12),('kids',0.12)]}
>>> d2 = {'0001': [('action', 0.89),('funny', 0.58),('sports',0.12)],'0002': [('dark', 0.89),('Mystery', 0.678),('crime',0.12), ('adult',-0.423)]}
>>> dict( (n, d1.get(n, []) + d2.get(n, [])) for n in set(d1)|set(d2) )
{'0001': [('skiing', 0.789), ('snow', 0.65), ('winter', 0.56), ('action', 0.89), ('funny', 0.58), ('sports', 0.12)], '0002': [('drama', 0.89), ('comedy', 0.678), ('action', -0.42), ('winter', -0.12), ('kids', 0.12), ('dark', 0.89), ('Mystery', 0.678), ('crime', 0.12), ('adult', -0.423)]}
```