# Is this code efficient? #LeetCode #two_sum

Tags: python, complexity-theory

This is [two sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/) problem from leetcode, I tried to solve, It got accepted. I am asking if this code is efficient enough in terms of memory and space complexity.

My code :

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        
        l = len(nums)
        ans = []
        for i in range(l):
            compliment = target - nums[i];
            # print(a.index(x))
            if compliment in nums:
                if nums.index(compliment)!=i:
                    # print(a.index(x))
                    ans.append(i)
                    ans.append(nums.index(compliment))
                    break;
        return ans
```

Comment: It got accepted, so clearly it is efficient enough. I don't get the question.

Comment: Right.  The goal is "solve the problem within the time limit."  You have done that, therefore it is by definition "efficient enough."

Comment: @RoboMop Not speaking for the others, but Stack Overflow normally deals with code that _isn't working yet_. There has to be a _specific_ problem that needs solving. The fact that this code is "working" and got "accepted", means there is no clear/specific problem to solve. "How to optimize" is rather open-ended, because there has to be a criteria for optimization (ex. cannot use a loop to iterate, O(1) storage). There is however a [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that deals with "*a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code*".

Comment: @GinoMempin You're absolutely right, but we can't consider what's technically correct when dealing with newbie questions. In this case, comments like Tim and Kelly's end up turning away people seeking simple answers that we can obviously provide. Again, you **are** technically correct, but the *right* thing to do is to help out OP and carry on with our day.

Comment: Besides, have you seen the number of top-voted questions on SO that aren't about "fixing non-working code"? Questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446128/python-append-vs-extend-efficiency are super helpful to the community, who cares if they aren't strictly aligned with the policies of SO.

Comment: @RoboMop Well the hope is that they use the feedback to improve the question accordingly.

Comment: I am disengaging @RoboMop because this is the classic divide/debate on what is the _right thing to do_ on StackOverflow, between the "helpers" and the "curators": https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367016/2745495.

Comment: @KellyBundy The "feedback" being "I don't get the question"? Apologies if I'm sounding aggressive here, but harsh comments on what are usually someone's first posts on SO are why people tend to run away from learning programming in general.

Comment: @GinoMempin agreed, this debate has been done to death, so there really is no right answer. All I'm saying, is maybe we could direct them to the right answer rather than outright dismissing the question in the comments?

Answer (score -1):

Your code searches for `compliment` in `nums`, and then follows it up with an index function. Later on, you use this index again in `nums.index(compliment)`. Essentially, you're searching through the array **three times**. A better way would be to search through the array and store the index if found, else `-1`. If the index is not `-1`, i.e., present in the array, you can append it to ans. This essentially skips the two lines (and that `index` function) and traverses the array once instead of thrice.

```py
index_if_found = -1
for index in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[index] == search_value:
        index_if_found = index
        break
```

You can now use this index `index_if_found` instead of using the `index` function.

EDIT: Thanks to Kelly for correcting me on the search algorithm.

---

Additionally, you have two `append` methods to the same array. A slightly faster approach would be to use the `extend` method and add them in the same operation. So instead of

```py
ans.append(i)
ans.append(nums.index(compliment))
```

You'd have

```py
ans.extend((i, nums.index(compliment)))
```